# Get list items even if user does not have access to those items

Tags: list, security, list-item, runwithelevatedprivileges, access

Is there a way to get items from a list even if the current user does not actually have acces to them? `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges` does not seem to work!

I have a special case in which I need to access some items from a list, items that respect a certain filter. The filter can return items that belong to other users and these are not returned.

But I need them to collect some information and display it to the user! The user won't see the items to which he does not have access to, but the information I'm displaying needs to take them into account.

Is it possible to do this without setting/removing permissions programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges` should do the trick.
Make sure, you create a new SPSite/SPWeb within the elevated code block:

```
var siteId = SPContext.Current.Site.ID;
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
  using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteId))
  {
    //do things on the new site object
  }
});
```

Comment: +1 for reminding me that the objects retrieved outside the delegate code run with the outside context and not under privileged context. My brain stepped out for a moment there...

Comment: Your code snippet isn't disposing of the `SPSite` you create, you need to have both the site and web creating in a `using` block.

Comment: @Servy - I can't see a problem in that code - the using will dispose of the SPSite he's created and he hasn't created SPWeb.